# Historical Mobile App Rankings/Downloads and Prices

Tags: data-request, economics, historical, programming

I am a PhD student in Economics who is starting a new research project on the mobile app market. For this project, I would ideally need historical data on the rankings (or downloads), prices, and reviews of all the apps in the Google Play/iTunes store. For example, I would like to see the daily/weekly ranking (or downloads) of Angry Birds in the "games" category in the iTunes store from the time it launched until today, as well as its price over that period.

I am aware that appannie.com and other internet marketing have such data, but they are geared towards businesses and are therefore prohibitively expensive. They also don't seem to have a program of sharing their data with researchers (I asked).

Is there anyone who has such data and would be willing to share it with me? It will be properly cited an attributed, and I will not use the data for any project except in an agreed-upon way.

Comment: I have a million+ downloads Android app and can release all of its statistics if that can be of any use to you. Installs/uninstalls/ratings/etc data  by country/language/device/version/etc. It is a free app though.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Ankidroid. Respect!

Comment: I'm currently doing my project in detection of fraud ranking of mobile applications. Along with the rankings I need reviews for each apps so that I can detect it somewhat accurately.

Answer (score 3):

I have shared the statistics of my 2 million+ downloads app here:

https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/google-play-statistics

Data available: Installs/uninstalls/ratings/crashes data by country/language/device/version/date/etc.

It is a free app for Android.

Answer (score 3):

Check http://androidrank.org , it contains data on android applications and it is for free.

Comment: This is great actually, voted up!

Answer (score 2):

There is an unofficial Android Market API (Java) where you can slowly collect all the data you may be interested in

**[Android Market API](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/)**

> This library allow you to ask directly google's official android market servers for information, search for apps, ...

[Github](https://github.com/jberkel/android-market-api)

There are ports for other languages (PHP, Ruby, etc) which are either linked in the above sites, or can be found by searching similarly.

*[my source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10273254/2327328)*